# What is the process number given by the "echo &" command?

Tags: bash, shell

Every time I run

```
echo &
```

...a different "process number" or PID is returned.

What are these for? Why is it different each time?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) than StackOverflow (hence answering community-wiki rather than under my own name, as I don't believe this question is in-scope for the site). As described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, SO is limited to questions that are "unique to software development"; the UNIX process model is relevant to *all* users, including folks using shells interactively and not doing software development at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` `fork()`s off a new copy of your shell (and uses `execve()` to replace that copy of the shell with an external program if you're running one, but `echo` isn't external). Thus, when you run `echo &`, you create a copy of your shell as a new process; it runs `echo`, and then it exits.

Every time a new process is started on UNIX -- which happens by `fork()`ing or `clone()`ing an existing process -- that new process gets a process ID number as an entry in the lookup table the operating system uses to refer to running programs; that's what you're seeing here.

Process IDs are the handles by which programs identify other programs, including to send signals to them or check their status (for example, to see if a program is still running; or, if it exited, to find out *how* it died). See [`waitpid()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) or [`kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) for examples of syscalls (operating-system-level requests) that need to be provided a PID to operate.

PIDs are assigned in such a way as to avoid frequent reuse -- that way you aren't likely to hit the wrong program by accident with a `kill()` signal (if the program you intended to target exited, and something else started up afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very simpler explanation.

The shell lets the user to type commands in order to do something useful. The user types a command, presses Enter, the command is executed, the user sees what happened, then it can start again with another command.

This happens because the shell, when instructed to execute a command, launches the command and **waits** for it to terminate. This is true even when the shell is given a list of commands to execute (such list of commands sits in a file, and it is called *script*).

There are commands which are not meant to give the user useful output (daemons, for example: they implement functionalities without user intervention). Or there can be other reasons/situations... where the user wants to execute a command **without waiting** for its completion; in case of a daemons, they are actually meant to never terminate by themselves.

If the user wants to run a command, but be able to interact with the shell while the command is running, he can append an ampersand to the command line. The ampersand, which means "together", tells the shell to lauch the command but **not** to wait for its termination - the shell works *together*, concurrently, with the invoked command (this does not mean they cooperate, in fact, they do not do).

At this point, the user knows that there is a running process he launched. But what if the user, after a while, decides to make something to that process? How can he address that precise process and not another, different one? This is why the shell prints out the process ID (PID) of the process just invoked: so the user knows **which** process is the one he launched.

The reason the OP sees different numbers every time, has been well explained by the reply from Charles. When a process terminates, its PID is no more in use, but the system tries to not (re)use the same PID for a while, because something (or someone) in the system could still think the process is alive, and try to kill it or whatever: it would be not nice to try to kill a process, just after the system has substituted that process with another...